# NSURLConnection taking a long time

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

This code loads a table view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //test data

    NSURL *url =[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
    //    NSLog(@"String to request: %@",url);
    [  NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url]
     queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init]
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
         if([data length] >0 && connectionError ==nil){
             NSArray *arrTitle=[[NSArray alloc]init];
             NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             arrTitle=    [Helper doSplitChar:[Helper splitChar20] :str];
             self.tableView.delegate = self;
             self.tableView.dataSource = self;
             [self fecthDataToItem:arrTitle];
             [self.tableView  reloadData];
             NSLog(@"Load data success");

         }else if (connectionError!=nil){
             NSLog(@"Error: %@",connectionError);
         }
     }];
    //    arrTitle = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ee",@"bb",@"dd", nil];

}
```

And it takes 10 - 15s to load. How can I make this faster?
.
Thanks Rob and rmaddy, problem is solve.

Comment: You need to do the UI updates on the main thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As rmaddy points out, you must do UI updates on the main queue. Failure to do so will, amongst other things, account for some of the problems you're experiencing.

The `queue` parameter of `sendAsynchronousRequest` indicates the queue upon which you want the completion block to run. So, you can simply specify `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if([data length] > 0 && connectionError == nil) {
        NSString *str      = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSArray  *arrTitle = [Helper doSplitChar:[Helper splitChar20] :str];
        self.tableView.delegate   = self;
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;
        [self fecthDataToItem:arrTitle];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } else if (connectionError!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",connectionError);
    }
}];
```

Or, if you where doing something slow or computationally expensive/slow within that block, go ahead and use your own background queue, but then dispatch the UI updates back to the main queue, e.g.:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

    // do something computationally expensive here

    // when ready to update the UI, dispatch that back to the main queue

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

        // update your UI here

    }];
}];
```

Either way, you should always do UI updates (and probably model updates, too, to keep that synchronized) on the main queue.